# SQL INSERT INTO table with different params

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I am currently working on a restaurant POS system in PHP and MySQL and have a table (open_tables) with the following values: 
code, idSeller, tableNo, products, netPrice

now I want to open the table, make changes and save it to a different table (sales) with extra params:
code, idSeller, tableNo, idCustomer, products, netPrice, discount, totalPrice, paymentMethod.

How can I go about this?

Here is what I currently have but it's giving me errors:

```
public static function ReopenSaleModel($table1, $table2, $data){

        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table2 SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE code, idSeller, tableNo, idCustomer, products, netPrice, discount, totalPrice, paymentMethod VALUES :code, :idSeller, :tableNo, :idCustomer, :products, :netPrice, :discount, :totalPrice, :paymentMethod");

        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $data["code"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idSeller", $data["idSeller"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tableNo", $data["tableNo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idCustomer", $data["idCustomer"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":products", $data["products"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":netPrice", $data["netPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":discount", $data["discount"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":totalPrice", $data["totalPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":paymentMethod", $data["paymentMethod"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            return "error";

        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the `insert ... select` syntax. This would look like:

```
INSERT INTO sales (
    code, 
    idSeller, 
    tableNo, 
    products, 
    netPrice,
    idSeller, 
    tableNo, 
    idCustomer, 
    products, 
    netPrice, 
    discount, 
    totalPrice, 
    paymentMethod
)
SELECT 
    code, 
    idSeller, 
    tableNo, 
    products, 
    netPrice,
    :idSeller, 
    :tableNo, 
    :idCustomer, 
    :products, 
    :netPrice, 
    :discount, 
    :totalPrice, 
    :paymentMethod
FROM open_tables
```

Note that I listed all the target columns for `insert`: this is a good practice that makes errors easier to tack down (you might need to adjust the actual column names of the target table)

Comment: It's now giving me a "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" error.

Comment: That's because you are binding parameter `:code` while it does not appear in the query. Maybe you want `INSERT ... SELECT :code, ... FROM ...` instead of  `INSERT ... SELECT code, ... FROM ...`? Or maybe it goes to a `WHERE` clause? I cannot tell without seeing more information, you would need to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Got it working using the following:

```
public static function ReopenSaleModel($table1, $table2, $data){

        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table2(code, idSeller, tableNo, idCustomer, products, netPrice, discount, totalPrice, paymentMethod) SELECT (:code), (:idSeller), (:tableNo), (:idCustomer), (:products), (:netPrice), (:discount), (:totalPrice), (:paymentMethod) FROM $table1");

        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $data["code"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idSeller", $data["idSeller"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tableNo", $data["tableNo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idCustomer", $data["idCustomer"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":products", $data["products"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":netPrice", $data["netPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":discount", $data["discount"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":totalPrice", $data["totalPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":paymentMethod", $data["paymentMethod"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            return "error";

        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = null;

    }
```